# In fabric2 Connection, how to take hosts argument in fab command line

Tags: python, fabric

In fabric2's task definition, how do I get the command line argument "-H --hosts"? Since I need to create connection myself.
eg.

```sh
fab -H web1,db1 task1
```

```py
@task
def task1(c):
  # HOW TO GET 'web1,db1' HERE???
  with Connection(host=???, connect_kwargs={}) as conn:
    conn.put('a','b')
    do_my_stuff()
```

Answer (score 0):

After a short while I figured it out.

```py
@task
def task1(ctx):
  with Connection(host=ctx.host, connect_kwargs={}) as c:
    c.put('a', '/tmp/a')
```